# Is $\{ 1, 2 \} \in \{ \{ 1, 2, 3 \}, \{ 1, 3 \}, 1, 2\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I recently picked up Robert R. Stoll's book, 'Set Theory and Logic' and whilst reading chapter 1.3, I came into the question posted above. It's salient to note that my mathematical knowledge in general rivals that of a 2nd grader (no offense to any 2nd graders), so this question brought me some trouble.

From what I learned in the book hitherto, a **set** is a collection of unique **elements** or **members**, so for example: $a \in \{ a, b, c \}$ is true because $a$ is an element within the given set. However, the brackets in the original question are throwing me off a bit because I am not too sure whether the $1$ and $2$ have to be within its own brackets e.g. $\{ 1, 2\}.$

In any case, I would have said that $\{ 1, 2 \}$ is indeed within $\{ \{ 1, 2, 3 \}, \{ 1, 3 \}, 1, 2 \},$ but that answer is said with soft conviction and some confusion. Hopefully someone with more mathematical prowess can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many elements does $\{ \{ 1, 2, 3 \}, \{ 1, 3 \}, 1, 2\}$ have? Is $\{1, 2\}$ one of them?

Comment: Henry - I am not too sure. Again, if my life was on the line (and I'm not saying it isn't), I would say that it is.

Comment: $\{1,2\} \subset \{ \{ 1, 2, 3 \}, \{ 1, 3 \}, 1, 2\}$ but not $\;\in\;$ so maybe that is your confusion is the word "within".

Comment: “Is within” is a different idea  entirely from “is a member of of.”

Comment: Your set has four elements. You should try to write out these four elements. Then it will be clear to you that none of these four elements is the set $\{1,2\}$.

Comment: The trick here is to replace the sets by letters. $\{1,2\}=a,\{1,2,3\}=b,\{1,3\}=c$. Now you are asking is it true that  $a\in\{b,c,1,2\}$. So, is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$A=\{\{1,2,3\},\{1,3\},1,2\}$ is a set with four elements: the two sets $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{1,3\}$, and the integers $1$ and $2$. $\{1,2\}$ is a *set* – even though the integers $1,2$ are contained in $A$, the set $\{1,2\}$ is not an element of $A$. (If it were, the set $\{1,2\}$ would be in the list of elements we wrote out to define $A$.)

As one of the comments notes, you can create a subset $\{1,2\}$, a smaller set that contains $1,2\in A$. However, there's a distinction between identifying an element of a set and creating subsets out of the elements of a set.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\{\{1,2,3\},\{1,3\},1,2\}$. The statement $\{1,2\} \in A$ is false because the set $\{1,2\}$ is not an *element* of $A$. It is, however, a *subset* of $A$, as both 1 and 2 are elements of $A$. So if you write $\{1,2\} \subseteq A$, this would be a true statement.

Answer (score 0):

We have 2 ways to interpret that:

1. $\{1,2\} \not\in \{\{1,2,3\},\{1,3\},1,2\},$
2. $ \{1,2\} \subset \{\{1,2,3\},\{1,3\},1,2\}.$

In the first case, we don't have the element $\{1,2\}$ in the main set, then they don't belong to the set. Notice that there are 4 elements in the the set $\{\{1,2,3\},\{1,3\},1,2\},$ they are $\{1,2,3\},\{1,3\},1 $ and $2$.

In the item 2, we can take any element $x \in  \{1,2\}$, then, they will be like $x=1$ or $x=2$, and both belongs to the main set, so we can see that $x \in \{\{1,2,3\},\{1,3\},1,2\}.$

Answer (score 0):

Just judge "mechanically": Given a set $\{a, b, c\}$ you'll get a list of its element by simply removing the outer braces: $a,b,c$.  Now in your case, removing the outer brackets from $\{\{1,2,3\},\{1,3\},1,2\}$ you get the list of the elements, namely
$$\{1,2,3\},\{1,3\},1,2.$$
As you see, $\{1,2\}$ is not in the list.

Now if you choose some elements of that list, say
$\{1,3\},1$ and put them in curly braces, you'll get a subset of the set, in our example
$$\{\{1,3\},1\}.$$